# Entity Framework - Loading Subclass Entities with TPT Setup

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Our system is receiving input from two external sources (phone call/web submission).

```
//  Table-Per-Type Hierarchy
public class Submission
{
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }   // Primary Key
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public long? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public bool? Completed { get; set; }
    public string AbsenceReason { get; set; }
    public string AbsenceType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AbsenceDate { get; set; }
}

public class CallSubmission : Submission
{
    public string CallerId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HangUp { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PickUp { get; set; }        
}

public class WebSubmission : Submission
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to retrieve all submissions within the past seven days using  *PickUp/SubmissionDate*  depending on the type of submission we're dealing with.  Is it possible to achieve this with a single LINQ statement? Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to load two different data sets in-memory.

***Statements I'm hoping to integrate***

```
Users.Where(user => user.UserName == name)
     .SelectMany(user => user.Submissions)
     .OfType<CallSubmission)()
     .Where(call => call.PickUp >= startDate)

Users.Where(user => user.UserName == name)
     .SelectMany(user => user.Submissions)
     .OfType<WebSubmission>()
     .Where(web => web.SubmissionDate >= startDate)
```

Comment: What's the problem with `UNION` query?

Comment: I shouldn't have used UNION there; I was referring to loading the two datasets and memory and then combining together.  I'd be open to an utilizing an SQL UNION statement if it's possible in this instance with LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually (surprisingly for me) what are you asking is possible (at least in the latest EF6.1.3) since the C# `is` and `as` operators are supported (they are basically used by `OfType` method).

```
var query = db.Users
    .Where(user => user.UserName == name)
    .SelectMany(user => user.Submissions)
    .Where(subm => (subm as CallSubmission).PickUp >= startDate
        || (subm as WebSubmission).SubmissionDate >= startDate);
```

The important part is to use `as` operator and not `cast` which generates unsupported exception. There is no need to check for `null` because the generated SQL query handles `NULL`s naturally.

Comment: Perfect - Thank you for the help!  It looks like all the properties are included for the various sub-types so it'll work great.